# The name 'P_G' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, wpf

Работаю с проектом WPF. Не видит переменную.

Просьба сильно не критиковать за вопрос, поскольку начал изучать C# , WPF пару дней назад.

Строка ошибки:    if (!P_G) //ОШИБКА ** Строка ошибки **

Код:

```
namespace Championship
{
    public partial class Create1 : Page
    {
        public object Create1(bool P_G)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StackPanel textInputStackPanel = new StackPanel();
            Button textInputeButton = new Button();
            TextBox textInputTextBox = new TextBox();
            textInputeButton.Content = "Open";

            textInputStackPanel.Children.Add(textInputeButton);
            textInputStackPanel.Children.Add(textInputTextBox);

            textInputStackPanel.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(OnTextInputKeyDown);
            textInputeButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(OnTextInputButtonClick);

            P_G = false;

            return P_G;
        }
        private void OnTextInputKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.O && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
            {
                handle();
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        private void OnTextInputButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            handle();
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        public object handle()
        {
            int b;

            if (!P_G)  //ОШИБКА
            {
                //ввод количества голов
                b = Convert.ToInt32(Tex.Text);
                Tex.Text = null;
                string bs = b.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show("Успешно Забито " + bs + " голов.");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Вы уже ввели количество голов. Если вы допустили ощибку, хотите исправить?");
            }

        }


    }
}
```

> Error 1 *The name 'P_G' does not exist in the current context*

Comment: А где код тот, который все это запускает?

Comment: Ну, объявите переменную на уровне класса хотя бы. На данный момент она у Вас только локально в методе Create1 объявлена.

Comment: Кстати, почему вы не пользуетесь XAML'ом?

Comment: VladD, пользуемся. Просто, для общего развития применил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Насколько я заметил - помимо того, что надо объявить P_G либо на уровне класса, либо передать в метод handle как параметр, необходимо в Create1 поставить перед параметром ref, т.к. вы пытаетесь в данный момент изменить именно параметр - зависит от нужного поведения.
+ Конструктор вроде как не может ничего возвращать...